# How to convert a text file into excel sheet using TCL and i need send that to through mail

Tags: excel, tcl

I have a text file, which is testcase results. which has 5 rows and 6 columns. I want to keep that in excel shell(i.e. converting a file to excel sheet format). and then i want to send to some specified user through mail.

Kindly someone give input on this. Let me know if there is predefined API or library to complete or anything else?

Comment: Is sending a CSV acceptable? Sometimes, as long as the data is importable into excel easily, it's doing what users want and CSVs are a lot easier to write than the XLS and XLSX formats…

Comment: yes writing as a CSV file also fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code below changes a Tcl list to a csv.

```
set data {T1 T2 T3 T4 T5
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
d1 d2 d3 d4 d5
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5}

set cols 5
set len [llength $data]
set rows [list]
set i 0

while {$i < $len} {
  set row [list]
  for {set j 0} {$j < $cols && $i < $len} {incr j; incr i} {
    set value [lindex $data $i]
    lappend row "\"[string map {\" \\\"} $value]\""
  }
  lappend rows [join $row ","]
}

puts [join $rows "\n"]
```

output:

```
"T1","T2","T3","T4","T5"
"a1","a2","a3","a4","a5"
"b1","b2","b3","b4","b5"
"c1","c2","c3","c4","c5"
"d1","d2","d3","d4","d5"
"e1","e2","e3","e4","e5"
```